# How one can unsource .sh format files?

Tags: sh, bash

Suppose that I have sourced a bunch of .sh files via a single file as

> source .bash_profile

Now, I want to use another installation. How can I un-source them before sourcing other .sh files? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no source history enabling you to do that.

If you want to run certain commands while having sourced certain files, you may run them in a new shell. Say:

```
sh -c "source your-env.sh; some-command.sh"
```